# Redirect to a custom page if DNS resolution fails

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system

Using Windows Server 2008 DNS. Not sure if this is going to be possible, but i would like to forward my clients to a custom HTML page if DNS resolution to an internal resource fails...

e.g. If there are records for:

serverA.intranet.company.com
serverB.intranet.company.com

Great, but if a user requests serverC.intranet.company.com (i.e. No DNS record) then redirect to a page saying: "The resource currently hasn't been made available for your use".

The use case here is we are only making certain company resources available to an external network, and want to be able to manage the user experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can accomplish what you are trying to do with a wildcard record and your suggested "landing page" hosted at the address.

> A wildcard DNS record is a record in a DNS zone that will match requests for non-existent domain names. A wildcard DNS record is specified by using a "*" as the leftmost label (part) of a domain name, e.g. *.example.com. The exact rules for when a wild card will match are specified in RFC 1034, but the rules are neither intuitive nor clearly specified. This has resulted in incompatible implementations and unexpected results when they are used.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record

Comment: I knew it was going to be something simple - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

- Create the page on ServerX.
- Create a wildcard DNS record for *.intranet.company.com that points to ServerX's IP.
- If ServerX is already hosting other sites, configure host headers on ServerX so that only requests for *.intranet.company.com are served the error page.